# Why manipulation of UIView on secondary thread doesn't throw an error?

Tags: multithreading, swift, uiview

If I understand right, UIView can only be edited from the main thread, because we want to avoid synchronization issues. Then why, when called from secondary thread, it sometimes works and sometimes not? (let's say I want to change the background color... it works approximately every 40 seconds). 
Why doesn't it work and yet it doesn't throw any error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIKit method will (very likely) not check on which thread they execute. If you call those methods on another thread, you get undefined behavior. That it's working "sometimes" is no proof of the opposite - instead, it's the evident of the fact that you get exactly this: *undefined behavior*.

Comment: ok, now I understand :) Could you please explain, how could this undefined behavior  pop up? i.e. why it occurs in this case? Can that be because of some race condition?

Comment: @Novellizator Yes, this is due to data races and other phenomena which occur when multiple threads accessing UIKit objects concurrently.